# In R, changing time labels when plotting a long realization of a stochastic process

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a long realization (T=5000) of a certain Time Series. I want a unique plot with 5x1 subplots. So, I would like to set the time labels as 1:1000, 1001:2000,..., 4001:5000.

```
T= 5000
X=rnorm(T)
# plot the time series
par(mfrow = c(5,1), mar = c(2,2,1,1))
for (i in 1:5) {
  start_idx <- (i-1) * 1000 + 1
  end_idx <- i * 1000
  plot(X[start_idx:end_idx], type="l", xlab="time", ylab="X_t^n")
}
```

The plot is
[image]
Note that in each subplot, the time labes are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

`plot` takes an optional `y` argument, so here, you can assign the corresponding time. See my modified example below where I create a time object `tt` of equal length and pass it to the `x` argument.

As an aside, note that `T` is a reserved word in `R`, so it's best to be careful and avoid using it as a variable name. I have, therefore, renamed `T` to `sample_size`.

```
sample_size = 5000 

tt = 1:sample_size #replace with your corresponding time/dates in your dataset

X = rnorm(sample_size)

# plot the time series

par(mfrow = c(5,1), mar = c(2,2,1,1))

for (i in 1:5) {
  start_idx <- (i-1) * 1000 + 1
  end_idx <- i * 1000
  plot(tt[start_idx:end_idx], X[start_idx:end_idx], type="l", xlab="time", ylab="X_t^n")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plotting just the y-axis values in the `plot`, add the `x=` and the `y=` explicitly:

```
...
plot(seq(start_idx, end_idx), X[start_idx:end_idx], type="l", xlab="time", ylab="X_t^n") 
...
```